# NuGet shows xunit.abstractions update but then says that nothing is compatible

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xunit.net

Recently in Visual Studio, the NuGet package manager started showing that xunit.abstractions has an update available. However, when we go to update it, we get the following error:

"Error: Updating 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.0' to 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.1' failed. Unable to find a version of 'xunit.extensibility.core' that is compatible with 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.1'."

How can we fix this? Alternately, how can we make it go away?

Answer (score 1):

For others who have wasted time trying to update xunit.abstractions, the xUnit team says to ignore the update notification:

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/939

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/968